# Rails Stripe has no attached payment source error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, devise, stripe-payments

I am getting this error when I try to create a new customer using devise and stripe. As you can see in my parameters I have the stripe_card_token and it's NOT blank. However I am still getting a no attached payment error. I have also tried using :card => token instead, but still getting the same error.

What am I doing wrong? I am using this on heroku. Rails 4. Ruby 2

[image]

Comment: You're using `self.stripe_card_token` so the obvious first step is to check if that's empty? Are you sure it's the proper way to retrieve the card token? Looking at the data you dumped it looked to be under `user`.

Comment: @koopajah I checked and like you guessed self.stripe_card_token was empty. I am rather new to rails, what should i use instead to get the token? thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd start by using `self.inspect?` to see what's in self and see if that works. Usually `params[:stripeToken]` should be what you're looking for though.